# STContains, STIntersects and STWithin return wrong result for geography loaded from WKT

Tags: sql-server, well-known-text, sql-server-spatial

I'm trying to determin whether a point is within a polygon. I created a polygon a two points with this tool: https://clydedacruz.github.io/openstreetmap-wkt-playground/

Polygon:

```
POLYGON((18.25103759765625 42.682771889291274,18.267517089843754 42.715741189305874,18.229064941406254 42.737262677320984,18.184204157441854 42.755415642264865,18.193359375 42.778267389968846,18.2647705078125 42.79170562395723,18.327941894531254 42.7876744539042,18.3746337890625 42.7735632912314,18.410339355468754 42.74062471803208,18.304138295352463 42.758104538811835,18.36090087890625 42.724485161605344,18.44879150390625 42.712377738077464,18.436889704316854 42.68613688294755,18.372802846133713 42.704977614599755,18.39202892035246 42.66392442101616,18.34533702582121 42.67200259850259,18.318786676973104 42.69757660890005,18.32244873046875 42.645744683373806,18.27850341796875 42.63025406904714,18.29040538519621 42.6672904969717,18.25103759765625 42.682771889291274))
```

First point:

```
POINT(18.241882380098104 42.964127551339516)
```

Second point:

```
POINT(17.793273953720927 43.26887292145395)
```

You can clearly see that non of the points lay within the polygon.

But if I try to run this query:

```sql
DECLARE @polygon geography;
SET @polygon = geography::STGeomFromText(
'POLYGON((18.25103759765625 42.682771889291274,18.267517089843754 42.715741189305874,18.229064941406254 42.737262677320984,18.184204157441854 42.755415642264865,18.193359375 42.778267389968846,18.2647705078125 42.79170562395723,18.327941894531254 42.7876744539042,18.3746337890625 42.7735632912314,18.410339355468754 42.74062471803208,18.304138295352463 42.758104538811835,18.36090087890625 42.724485161605344,18.44879150390625 42.712377738077464,18.436889704316854 42.68613688294755,18.372802846133713 42.704977614599755,18.39202892035246 42.66392442101616,18.34533702582121 42.67200259850259,18.318786676973104 42.69757660890005,18.32244873046875 42.645744683373806,18.27850341796875 42.63025406904714,18.29040538519621 42.6672904969717,18.25103759765625 42.682771889291274))'
, 4326);
DECLARE @pointIn geography;
SET @pointIn = geography::STGeomFromText ('POINT(18.241882380098104 42.964127551339516)' , 4326 );

DECLARE @pointOut geography;
SET @pointOut = geography::STGeomFromText ( 'POINT(17.793273953720927 43.26887292145395)', 4326 );

SELECT @polygon.STContains( @pointOut) AS 'STContains', 
    @polygon.STIntersects( @pointOut) AS 'STIntersects', 
       @pointOut.STWithin( @polygon ) AS 'STWithin';

SELECT @polygon.STContains( @pointIn) AS 'STContains', 
    @polygon.STIntersects( @pointIn) AS 'STIntersects', 
       @pointIn.STWithin( @polygon ) AS 'STWithin';
```

I get results for both point to be true (1) for `STContains`, `STIntersects` and `STWithin`.

```
STContains  STIntersects    STWithin
1   1   1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Your polygon seems to wind clockwise. For geography type in MSSQL Server that means that the polygon is filling the whole world except the area what you think it fills.

[image]

Turn the polygon around with ReorientObject https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/reorientobject-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15